# How to split array and return it in column javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to split the return data and make it column.

Here is my data.

```
var data = [
 {"name":"jer@yahoo.com","person":"trake@org.com,kendar@org.com","date":"07/06/2020 16:04:50","class":"Lanter"},
{"name":"terry@yahoo.com","person":"trakedds@org.com,relak@org.com","date":"07/06/2020 16:04:50","class":"Lanter"},
]
```

And here i return the data.

```
var name= "",
person= "",
date= "",
class="";


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var name= data[i].name,
    person= data[i].persom,
    class= data[i].class
     switch () {
   
  }


<td>${data[i].name}</td>
<td>${data[i].person}</td>
<td>${data[i].date}</td>
<td>${data[i].class}</td>
```

Expected output should be this

```
jer@yahoo.com   trakedds@org.com     07/06/2020   Lanter
                kendar@org.com
```

The problem is the data of 'person' is not splitting when ive tried to return it.
I just want to seperate if he have more emails.. it should goes down. Ive tried to put some 
 but doesnt work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace commas with breaks:

```
${data[i].person.replace(/,/g, "<br>")}
```

Or with the newer method `replaceAll`:

```
${data[i].person.replaceAll(",", "<br>")}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this ;-)